# Mobile version doesn't have markup tips

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web

I often browse and answer questions on my mobile. However, I cannot see any markdown tips when browsing on my phone. Can you add a tips link on the mobile style sheet so that someone can view markdown styles while answering/commenting from a mobile phone?

My mobile Operating System: Android 2.3.3

Answer (score 1):

The mobile site has many shortcomings. Reviewing posts, vote count (+1/-1) and presenting markup info and probably more.

I go about those things by viewing the site in `full site` modus on my Nexus 4. I have a few suggestion for you:

1. Buy a smartphone with a screen diagonal of at least 4,3 inch and view the site in `full site` modus. Android 4 and higher recommendable.
2. Memorize all the markup styles
3. Copy all styles in a Google Document, so that you can switch from mobile viewing to the markup style document back and forth.
4. Get the attention of Jin and trigger him to respond.

Beyond that, it out of my grasp.